# Responsive Navigation Visability - jQuery Show Hide

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I've just rebuilt my site from scratch and have a small issue i cant seem to fix myself on the responsive navigation.

If you view the site full size then resize the screen, at 400px the responsive nav kicks in. If you open the nav and close it again then resize the browser beyond 400px the menu remains hidden.

You can view here: http://roybarber.com

The jquery is in functions.min.js and also below:

```
    $.fn.collapsable = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
  var obj = $(this);
  var tree = $('.main');
  obj.click(function(){
    if( obj.is(':visible') ){tree.slideToggle('fast');tree.toggleClass('clearfix');}
  });
  $(window).resize(function(){
    if ( $(window).width() >= 767 ){ tree.toggleClass('clearfix'); };
  });
});
};
var menubtn = $('.menu-btn');
menubtn.collapsable();
menubtn.click(function(ev) {
    menubtn.toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: I cannot produce the misbehaviour you describe in Google Chrome.

Comment: Hi @Mika, You need to have the website at more than 800px wide, then resize the browser untill the menu changes to the mobile version with the icon in the top right. click the icon, the menu will open, click again to close. Now resize the browser back to above 800px and you will notice the nav has vanished!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Junaid Ahmed ([@simple_ux](https://twitter.com/simple_ux)) on twitter

the fix was so simple! add .show here:

```
    if ( $(window).width() >= 600 ){ tree.toggleClass('clearfix').show(); };
```

Also had to correct the browser .width to match the media query, Heres the full code

```
    $.fn.collapsable = function(options) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var obj = $(this);
        var tree = $('.main');
        obj.click(function(){
          if( obj.is(':visible') ){tree.slideToggle('fast');tree.toggleClass('clearfix');}
        });
        $(window).resize(function(){
          if ( $(window).width() >= 600 ){ tree.toggleClass('clearfix').show(); };
        });
      });
    };
    var menubtn = $('.menu-btn');
    menubtn.collapsable();
    menubtn.click(function(ev) {
      menubtn.toggleClass('open');
    });
```